# Inline styles not being applied in ASP.NET/ CSHTML

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Just a quick example:

`<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px;">
<input type="submit" value="Create" style="margin: 10px" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>`

If I serve up the page that contains this HTML the margin and padding style will not take affect unless I inspect the element and manually toggle them off then back on using chrome dev tools.

Is there a way to get inline styles to load correctly? Thanks!

Comment: The styles seem correct.  Are you sure there is no other CSS overwriting these inline styles?  You may also be falling victim to your browser cache(if your using chrome shift+F5 will refresh the page and clear the cache).

Comment: No CSS that I can see would be affecting either of these scenarios .I checked the site.less and site.css files. I even tried both  HTML elements without the class attribute. Similar results. The div, nothing happened, the input, well obviously no longer looked like a bootstrap btn.

Comment: then I am back to thinking that it is a browser caching issue.  Try your page in incognito mode or something of the sort and see if the styles are taking there.  I just copied and pasted your code into an html sandbox and it rendered with the styles, no problem.

Comment: Neither of those solutions worked. Thanks for trying to help. I'm thinking it has something to do with MVC/Razor. But I'm really reaching. Only because there isn't any other CSS styles being applied over these two elements.

Comment: Have you tried to enforce your inline style with the `!important` marker to ensure that nothing is overriding the style?  `<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:10px !important;">`

Comment: @Tommy, was worth a try, but !important made no difference. The behavior remains the same. The page is initially rendered with no padding in the div. If I inspect the div in chrome dev tools the padding is toggled on. If I toggle it off then back on, suddenly it's applied.

Comment: I figured out my problem. Everything was inside of a bootstrapped div that was applying it's cancer to everything inside. Got rid of it, works perfectly. Thank you to everyone who took time to help!